# Change a value in a table by clicking on it

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I'm new with React, and am trying to set up a table (actually, an array) where I can click on one of the values to change it. This is what I got so far:

```
function Cache() {

    const cache = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    const clickHandler = (e) => {
            e.target.value = '42'
            console.log('clicked')
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    {cache.map((value, index) => {
                        return <td key={index} onClick={clickHandler} > {value} </td>
                    })}
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens :(. And the console shows that it was clicked, but only on the first click.

Can anybody help me? Is it possible to use onClick in , or only with buttons? Do I need to use the table values as states? Or use the useEffect-function?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to toggle *some* edit "state" for a specific component/element being rendered? Or do you just want to click on an element and assign a random value? Can you provide a bit more context for what you want to accomplish. Show us code you've tried already on your own? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Finally, what I want to do is to visualise the "paging algorithm" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_replacement_algorithm). We have a cache with limited size, an input is coming, and I need to decide which value in my cache should be overwritten.
At the moment, I will overwrite with "42", later it will be another input from another function.

Comment: Well, caching strategies and editing UI are two completely different things. Which are you really asking about? Are you wanting to keep a list of the last N edited/clicked values?

Comment: The problem in this algorithm is to have a limited cache and replace its values, depending on the (unlimited) input stream with random numbers. This snipped is only one part of the solution for this algorithm.
Danial has provided the solution below. However, thank you, Drew, for your assistance. I appreciate.

Comment: Sure. I was going to suggest a state update function like `setCache(cache => [...cache, value].slice(-5))` to append new values and keep only the last 5 elements, if you were looking for a "caching strategy".

Comment: Thank you for this hint! This might be useful in my future elaboration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must get `index` of cache array in clickHandler. Then you can update the array based on the `index`. Finally with `useState` hook update table.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [cache, setCache] = useState([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);

  const clickHandler = (index) => {
    console.log("clicked ", index);
    let newCache = [...cache]; // copying the old datas array
    newCache[index] = 42;
    setCache(newCache);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          {cache.map((value, index) => {
            return (
              <td key={index} onClick={() => clickHandler(index)}>
                {value}
              </td>
            );
          })}
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```